# How to make Eclipse as a Default Editor FOREVER in Mac OS-X?

Tags: eclipse, macos, open-with

The way with `Get Info > Open with > Change All` bla .. bla .. bla .. doesn't work actually. When i set these way for a type `.php` (for example), it always open with XCode **next time**.

I've set `File Association` inside Eclipse already. But whatever, it doesn't work.

So how to solve it?
*My Eclipse is `Helios` on Mac OS X 10.7.3.*

Comment: It works fine here like you describe it. Well with komodo edit, but should be the same. Maybe no rights todo?

Comment: I'm the Admin who with full rights todo :( Please refer to the `Umut Kaya` answer below. My problem is at `Step 9` in his list. The `Eclipse` is NOT LISTED at that step, in the `Open with` list, but i followed all above steps exactly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right click on file and choose "get info", then in the "open with" section, apply by clicking "change all".

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this per file type. I found it on [Tech-recipes](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2573/os_x_how_to_change_default_application_to_open_file_type/)

1. Ctrl-click on the file you want to open
2. Click Open with
3. Select Other
4. Select the applcation you want to open the file
5. Select Always Open With
6. Click Open button
7. Ctrl-click on the file again
8. Click Get Info
9. Under Open With pick the app that you want to become the default
10. Click the Change All button

I hope this helps

Comment: I've told about this way already in my question, and `it doesn't work`.

Comment: The problem is.. when re-check the `Open With` (the Step-9 in your list), its not showing my previously selected app (since, Step-4).

Comment: Whoops, sorry.
Then it should be that you do not have the permissions to do so.
Out of curiosity, is there a way to actually "install" eclipse on osx like in Linux? The downloads in eclipse.org are like portable, you just extract and it runs. But on Linux you can also use apt-get install eclipse. Maybe you need to find an actual installer, so it will add to the list of applications?
And how does this work for you http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030730161311391

Comment: I'm the `only` user of this Mac and the `Admin` as well with full permission.

Comment: Could you try http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030730161311391 and add the suffixes you want in eclipse app? Maybe then it will be visible/setable?

Comment: Just do steps 8 to 10. Works with Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

I've use the method I describe [here](http://bewarethepenguin.blogspot.com/2010/08/setting-up-java-files-to-automatically.html) on 3 or 4 different Macs and it always has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had to uninstall Adobe Flash Builder, so that Eclipse could be selected from the list.
(Eclipse.app was greyed out in the list of apps and Flash Builder kept setting itself as default app).

`Get Info > Open with > Change All` worked for me.

Comment: I guess that was because you had to switch to "All applications" in Finder, by default is "Recommended Applications" and Max OS X does not think Eclipse is recommended to open a xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Install this plugin on eclipse : 
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/default-text-editor